# how to get previous element using jsoup from my current element instance using jsoup

Tags: jsoup

I have some html like this:

```
<---Some HTML code before --->
<label class="inputLabel" for="zipCodeEntry" style="display: block;">zip code</label>
<input id="zipCodeEntry" class="login" type="text" value="" maxlength="5" name="zipcode">
<---Some HTML code before --->
```

My Java Code

```
Elements formElements =  doc.getElementsByTag("form");
for(Element formElem : formElements){
     Elements inputElements = formElem.getElementsByTag("input");
     for(Element inputElem : inputElements){
         String name = inputElem.attr("name");
        /* Need to scrape label text here. I've inputElemen Object here.*/
     }
}
```

Question:
I've instance of inputElem as mentioned the above code, i want the previous element of the input element. Previous element of input element differs every time. we don't know which tag element will be the previous element of input element. I've to go through input element only. So if i say get the previous tag element of input element it should give me previous tag element whatever tag it is

Comment: My Java Code :-Elements formElements = doc.getElementsByTag("form"); for(Element formElem : formElements){ Elements inputElements = formElem.getElementsByTag("input"); for(Element inputElem : inputElements){ String name = inputElem.attr("name"); /* Need to scrape label text here. I've inputElemen Object here.*/ } } }

Comment: You should be able to revise your question with the "edit" link instead of adding comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could parse all of the form elements (its children elements), and if you come across a `<input>` tag, get the text from the previous child tag.

Example:

```
Elements formElements =  doc.getElementsByTag("form");            // select all of the forms from the document
for(Element formElem : formElements) {
    Elements formChildren = formElem.select("*");                 // select all child tags of the form
    for(Element formChild : formChildren) {
        if (formChild.tagName().equals("input")) {                // if the child is <input>
             String name = formChild.attr("name");                // get <input> name attribute
             String label = formChildren
               .get(formChildren.indexOf(formChild) - 1).text();  // get text from previous child element
        }
    }
}
```

So in this example, `name` will be "zipcode" and `label` will be "zip code". It doesn't matter what the element before `<input>` is, because it just retrieves any elements with an index of `i-1` and retrieves its `text()` value.

This will work well for the html you provided, but you may need to tweak it depending on the complexity of your html forms. Also be careful of `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: Thanks for providing solution

Comment: @HarisuryaprakashTurangi glad to help, if this solved your problem don't forget to accept the answer :)